# Test connection string within Entity Framework for incorrect password

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-connection

I'm a beginner with Entity Framework (Code First) and I have to modify an application.

I have my Context class that inherits from DbContext. In the constructor, I pass the connectionString.

Code sample (not mine) :

```
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities(string paramType, string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }
}
```

But I don't understand where the connection is done. I would like to catch the error if the password given in the connectionString is wrong, then try to connect with another password, and catch the event when I am connected to the database.

How can I do that ?

Comment: how about a try/catch?

Comment: Yes but where ? I don't find where the connection is done. Sorry if the question is stupid!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are asking, `How can I detect if the connection string is valid.`

The [DbContext.Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database(v=vs.113).aspx) has a Property called [Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.connection(v=vs.113).aspx) that you  can use to retrieve the connection Entity Framework will use.  You can then call [Open()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx) to test the connection itself.

Comment: thx for the answer! Where is the connection to the database actually done ? Is is automatic at the creation of the Context ? Can I simply  add a Try/Catch somewhere ?

Comment: I believe you mean is: *Where in code is the connection to the database **opened***.  It is most likely deep with EF and as far as I am aware, there are no events like `ConnectionOpening` or `ConnectionOpened` that you can subscribe to.  It is done automatically and I don't believe you can easily add a try/catch to each and every EF line of code that opens a connection.

Comment: Ok thx, and is there a way to change the connectionString at runtime, when the Open() is called and I get an error ? (I would like to change the password and retry)

Comment: I'm not sure, but since that is a different and useful question, I recommend searching StackOverflow and if you don't find an answer, ask that as another question.

Answer (score 0):

How to check the connection string for a context is different depending on the version of EF you are using.

```
//Entity Framework 5
myContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
//Entity Framework 6
myContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
//Entity Framework Core 1
myContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString
```

Check out this blog post I wrote about it - [http://NoDogmaBlog.bryanhogan.net/2016/04/entity-framework-checking-the-connection-string-of-your-context/](http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/04/entity-framework-checking-the-connection-string-of-your-context/)